# c++ function call for char as parameter

Tags: c++

I have my function defined as the following

```
void initBoard(char board[3][3]){
    for (int x=0; x<3; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<3;y++){
            board[x][y] = '-';
            std::cout << board[x][y];
            if (y == 0 || y == 1){
                std::cout << '|';
            }
            else if (y == 2){
                std::cout << std::endl;
                if (x != 2){
                    std::cout << "-----" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            }
        }
}
```

how do i call this function in my `int main()` function to print the board?

Can I do this

```
int main(){
    initBoard(char board[3][3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Edited: I fixed it, but I still want to understand the logic of c++ for function calls
What I did is

```
int main(){
    char board[3][3];
    initBoard(board);
    return 0;
}
```

By declaring the board first, if I have any other functions need `char board[3][3]` as parameter I have to declare it in the function parameter first and declare it once in main function in order to make any function calls?

Comment: BTW, you should split your function into `printBoard` and `InitBoard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, the compiler needs to know these things about a parameter,

1. The type of the parameter.
2. The name of the variable (optional).
3. Default argument (optional).

When you define a parameter (in your case `char board[3][3]`), this just works as a container. Just picture this, when your at an airport, they give you buckets to put your belongings when you go through the metal detector. The bucket is the parameter variable in this, and your belongings are the data. Sending an empty bucket wont work right? So you need to provide it with data (with the exception of you providing an default argument).

This is the reason behind why doing this flagged an error,

```cpp
int main(){
    initBoard(char board[3][3]);
    return 0;
}
```

But this didn't,

```cpp
int main(){
    char board[3][3];
    initBoard(board);
    return 0;
}
```

In simpler terms, this: `void initBoard(char board[3][3])` and this: `char board[3][3]` are two separate things. One is a way the function stores data for processing and the other is the main variable which contains your data.